# What Are _vti Files and Can They Be Deleted?

Tags: web-hosting, frontpage

I inherited a website and along with it, messy file keeping and tons of _vti folders. I'd like to do some clean up, but what are these VTI folders and can they be deleted?

From what I can find (which are old postings/articles), these are related to Front Page. I don't use Front Page, never did. I use Sublime.

When I did a WHOIS search, I got this information for the hosting:

Hosting provider: MyHosting  / Name Servers:
ns5.softcomca.com
ns6.softcomca.com

I don't know if that matters in relation to whether these folders can be deleted.

Comment: sheesh, FrontPage? Now there's a blast from the past. https://serverfault.com/questions/437714/can-i-safely-remove-vti-folders-added-by-my-host-or-cpanel

Answer (score 1):

Is the website using any Frontpage specific functions?  Perhaps a counter or something specific to Frontpage (it's been way too long since Frontpage was a thing, I can't remember all of the special functions it provided).

I would really say they can be deleted.  Frontpage has been end-of-life'd for probably 10 years now.  While you can probably delete them, it's never a bad idea to download the directories and files in those directories just for safe keeping, just in case.